# Vb.net How do i link different databases to different charts

Tags: database, vb.net, charts

I need to link Series 1(Graph1) to 1RosterMonday and Series 2 (Graph 2) to 2RosterTuesday.

The following code works with connecting series 1 to 1RosterMonday, however i am not sure how to link Series 2 (Graph 2) to 2RosterTuesday.

This is my current code:

```
    '====Connection String to connect to access database
    Dim strConn As String = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & _
    ";Persist Security Info=False;"

    '====Query String
    Dim tblFields As String = "SELECT * from 1RosterMonday "

    '====Connecting to Data base and storing the data in a dataset
    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
    Dim oCmd As New OleDbCommand(tblFields, conn)
    Dim oData As New OleDbDataAdapter(tblFields, conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet


    conn.Open()
    oData.Fill(ds, "1RosterMonday")
    conn.Close()


    '====Set Data source
    Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables("1RosterMonday")
    Dim Series1 As Series = Chart1.Series("Series1")
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).YValuesPerPoint = 2
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "Name"
    Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "Start Time , End Time"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the Tuesday information in the same database, why not just repeat the same process for the second chart with a new query?

But if you also have more days of the week to build charts for, you should try making this into a function:

```
Sub linkDataToChart(strConnection as String, strRoster as String, chtDest as Chart)

    'Build Connection String
     Dim strConn As String = _
     "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strConnection & _
     ";Persist Security Info=False;"

     'Build Query String
     Dim tblFields As String = "SELECT * from " & strRoster

     'Retrieve Data from Database
     Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(strConn)
     Dim oCmd As New OleDbCommand(tblFields, conn)
     Dim oData As New OleDbDataAdapter(tblFields, conn)
     Dim ds As New DataSet

     conn.Open()
     oData.Fill(ds, strRoster)
     conn.Close()

     'Set Data source
     chtDest.DataSource = ds.Tables(strRoster)
     Dim Series1 As Series = chtDest.Series("Series1")
     chtDest.Series(Series1.Name).YValuesPerPoint = 2
     chtDest.Series(Series1.Name).XValueMember = "Name"
     chtDest.Series(Series1.Name).YValueMembers = "Start Time , End Time"

End Sub
```

Then you can call this function for both days:

```
linkDataToChart(Textbox1.Text, "1RosterMondays", Chart1)
linkDataToChart(Textbox1.Text, "2RosterTuesdays", Chart2)
```